# Bad state: Migrate To flutter_bloc v8.0.1

Tags: flutter, url-rewriting, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am trying to fix an issue related to Flutter Bloc. I am editing someone else code to make it work with the latest flutter_bloc version but I am unable to do so. Can someone do a rewrite for my code so I can run it? I saw many answers but I am unable to understand how to fix my own code.

This is the complete code for all_categories_bloc.dart

```
    class AllCategoriesBloc extends Bloc<AllCategoriesEvent, AllCategoriesState> {
  AllCategoriesBloc({
    this.apiRepository,
  }) : super(AllCategoriesInitial()) {
    on<GetAllCategories>(_onGetAllCategories);
  }

  final ApiRepository apiRepository;

  Future<void> _onGetAllCategories(
    GetAllCategories event,
    Emitter<AllCategoriesState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      emit(const AllCategoriesLoading());

      final categoriesModel = await apiRepository.fetchCategoriesList();

      emit(AllCategoriesLoaded(categoriesModel));

      if (categoriesModel.error != null) {
        emit(AllCategoriesError(categoriesModel.error));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        const AllCategoriesError(
          "Failed to fetch all categories data. Is your device online ?",
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Code for all_categories_event.dart

```
abstract class AllCategoriesEvent extends Equatable {
  AllCategoriesEvent();
}

class GetAllCategories extends AllCategoriesEvent {

  @override
  List<Object> get props => null;

}
```

Code for all_categories_state.dart

```
abstract class AllCategoriesState extends Equatable {
  const AllCategoriesState();
}

class AllCategoriesInitial extends AllCategoriesState {
  AllCategoriesInitial();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AllCategoriesLoading extends AllCategoriesState {
  const AllCategoriesLoading();
  @override
  List<Object> get props => null;
}

class AllCategoriesLoaded extends AllCategoriesState {

  final CategoriesModel categoriesModel;
  const AllCategoriesLoaded(this.categoriesModel);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [categoriesModel];
}

class AllCategoriesError extends AllCategoriesState {

  final String message;
  const AllCategoriesError(this.message);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

It throws an error "Bad state: add(GetAllCategories) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...})"

I have this add(GetAllCategories) in my home. dart file but the solution is to edit this code which I am unable to do so. Can someone do a rewrite for the latest bloc? I would be thankful.

Comment: If you are looking for someone doing that job, you may want to hire a professional software developer. If you need help doing it yourself, please tell us what you tried and where you are currently stuck so we can help you with that specific problem.

Comment: Have you checked the [migration guide](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=v800)?

Comment: Yes i did. I am unable to understand what to change. That's why i asked someone help to do a rewrite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's get through the migration guide step by step:

1. > `package:bloc` v5.0.0: initialState has been removed. For more information check out [#1304](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1304).

You should simply remove the `AllCategoriesState get initialState => AllCategoriesInitial();` portion from your BLoC.

2. > `package:bloc` v7.2.0 Introduce new on<Event> API. For more information, [read the full proposal](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2526).

As a part of this migration, the `mapEventToState` method was removed, each event is registered in the constructor separately with the `on<Event>` API.

First of all, register your events in the constructor:

```
AllCategoriesBloc() : super(AllCategoriesInitial()) {
  on<GetAllCategories>(_onGetAllCategories);
}
```

Then, create the `_onGetAllCategories` method:

```
Future<void> _onGetAllCategories(
  GetAllCategories event,
  Emitter<AllCategoriesState> emit,
) async {
  try {
    emit(const AllCategoriesLoading());

    final categoriesModel = await _apiRepository.fetchCategoriesList();

    emit(AllCategoriesLoaded(categoriesModel));

    if (categoriesModel.error != null) {
      emit(AllCategoriesError(categoriesModel.error));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    emit(
      const AllCategoriesError(
        "Failed to fetch all categories data. Is your device online ?",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice, that instead of using generators and yielding the next state, you should use the `Emitter<AllCategoriesState>` emitter.

Here is the final result of the migrated `AllCategoriesBloc`:

```
class AllCategoriesBloc extends Bloc<AllCategoriesEvent, AllCategoriesState> {
  AllCategoriesBloc() : super(AllCategoriesInitial()) {
    on<GetAllCategories>(_onGetAllCategories);
  }

  final ApiRepository _apiRepository = ApiRepository();

  Future<void> _onGetAllCategories(
    GetAllCategories event,
    Emitter<AllCategoriesState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      emit(const AllCategoriesLoading());

      final categoriesModel = await _apiRepository.fetchCategoriesList();

      emit(AllCategoriesLoaded(categoriesModel));

      if (categoriesModel.error != null) {
        emit(AllCategoriesError(categoriesModel.error));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        const AllCategoriesError(
          "Failed to fetch all categories data. Is your device online ?",
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Bonus tip**

Instead of creating an instance of `ApiRepository` inside the BLoC directly, you can use the constructor injection:

```
class AllCategoriesBloc extends Bloc<AllCategoriesEvent, AllCategoriesState> {
  AllCategoriesBloc({
    required this.apiRepository,
  }) : super(AllCategoriesInitial()) {
    on<GetAllCategories>(_onGetAllCategories);
  }

  final ApiRepository apiRepository;

  ...
}
```

Now, when creating BLoC, pass the instance of the repository to the constructor, like `AllCategoriesBloc(apiRepository: ApiRepository())`. This way you will be able to properly unit test your BLoC by mocking dependencies (in this case, `ApiRepository`).

Comment: It works and now i understand how to do it. Thank you for good explanation but the data is not coming. It says no categories and in the previous version of bloc. I can see the categories so backend is working fine. Can you assist on this so i can mark this as an answer

Comment: It throws an error saying "Failed to fetch all categories data. Is your device online ?". I am online btw

Comment: See this : https://imgur.com/a/JUw1idP. I have also added it to the salons bloc and they also don't show up. Upon clicking the forward key. A red screen comes up and i see "Bad state: add(GetAllMySalons) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on<GetAllMySalons>((event, emit) {...})"

Comment: See my updated code on top as you suggested.

Comment: I have changed {
    required this.apiRepository,
  } to old code like it was before final ApiRepository _apiRepository = ApiRepository(); and the data is now coming. i have marked it as an answer. Thanks alot mate!

Comment: However, I am getting errors when clicking on any category. Same error as I mentioned above Bad state: add(GetCategorySalons) was called without a registered event handler. Make sure to register a handler via on<GetAllMySalons>((event, emit) {...})"

Comment: This is because you should migrate all the BLoCs in your project. Do not start a discussion in the comments, you should create a separate question if needed.

Comment: Ok mate thanks!